# Access int16_t as char*

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm writing a networking application using sockets in c++ so lets jump straight to the problem : 
i'm storing my data as an array of int16_ts (the choice of int16_t being for consistency accross different platforms) , as we know each of these int16_ts would be two consecutive bytes in memory. i want to store each of those bytes in a char so that each int16 would be translated to exactly two bytes and eventually send the entire char* over the socket

please notice that i'm not looking for something such as std::to_string cause i want each int16_t to occupy exactly two bytes.

any help is appreciated !

Comment: You need to take care sending and receiving in network byte order (lookup `htons()` et al.). Besides that just cast, and specify size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to copy each `int16_t` one at a time to the `char *` buffer, calling `htons()` on each one to translate the bytes into network byte order.  Then on the receiving side, you would call `ntohs()` to convert back.

```
int send_array(int16_t *myarray, int len, int socket) {
    char buf[1000];
    int16_t *p;
    int i;

    p = (int16_t *)buf;
    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
        p[i] = htons(myarray[i]);
    }
    return send(socket,buf,len*sizeof(int16_t),0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! thats what i was looking for. i didn't think of writing directly to the char* using an int pointer .

Comment: @dbush @Parsoa `p = (int16_t *)buf` violates strict aliasing rule, so it is undefined behavior. You should do the opposite: treat `int16_t*` as `char*`. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Answer (score 0):

C++ has a new type, `char16_t`, that's designed to hold UTF-16 characters.  If you mean you want to send the 16-bit hints over the wire one byte at a time, convert each one to network byte order with `htons()`, store them in a new array of `uint16_t`, then send that array over the socket.  If you want to address the array of shorts as an array of bytes, you can do that either through a union, with a pointer cast, or with a reference to an array.  Example: `char* const p=reinterpret_cast<char*>(&shorts[0]);`.